# Get name of clicked point in Highcharts when the point has drilldown

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a pie chart where one of the points have drilldown and the other points do not. When I detect a click using plotOptions.series.point.events.click and try to return the name of the clicked point, it works for every point except the one with drilldown.

If I do:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    point: {
      events: {
        click: function(e) {
          console.log(this.name);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then the proper name would show up for every point except the one with drilldown, which would return a null point. It might be because the graph updates first via drilldown and the point no longer exists when the event callback occurs. How can I make it so that both the regular points and drilldown points return properly when clicked?

I added a JSFiddle to illustrate my point:
http://jsfiddle.net/Pq6gb/2/
I just took the pie drilldown example from Highcharts demo page and made it so that Firefox does not have a drilldown. Note in the browser's console that when I click Firefox, the name gets displayed. When I click any other slice, the displayed name is null.

Comment: please create a fiddle of your code

Comment: JSFiddle added to my original question.

Comment: Word of explanation: It's caused by calling `drilldown` event before `point.click` - in `drilldown` event, clicked point is destroyed. I will see why first we call `drilldown`, then `click` event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although not ideal, this would give you some event for regular and drilldown:

```
chart: {
    ...,
    events: {
        drilldown:  function (e) {
            console.log(e.point); // The point, with name, that was clicked
        }
    }
}
```

Along with your own code this would fire one event for regular points (your own code), and two events for drilldown points. You would then be able to check `name == null` in  `series.point.events.click`, and ignore it, and handle it in `chart.events.drilldown` ([API reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.drilldown)).

Answer (score 7):

This is fixed now in the current development version of drilldown.src.js: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/Pq6gb/3/

```
point: {
    events: {
        click: function(e) {
            console.log(e.type, this.name);
        }
    }
}
```